# Vue.js2 Applications is not responding in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am new vue.js. My whole application is working fine in chrome and safari. But as I open my website in IE broweser(IE-11) it display a message "This page can't be displayed". I go through my stackover flow solution and found I have to add babel-pollyfill. But its not working for me.
I add  `"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",` and import this in my main.js file. But it's not working. Please help me for solving this problem.

Comment: Please add the _version_ of IE to the question.  Could be relevant.

Comment: I am using IE-11

Comment: Just importing the polyfill won't do the trick, you have to prepend it to your entry point(s) in Webpack: `entry: { app: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js')] }`

Comment: I add entry: { app:  ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js')] } – in my webpack.base.config.js file. But it's not working